# Android StickyListHeaders on Single Item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm using the library [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders#stickylistheaders) and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get it to work for my specific application. I want to have a sticky header on the second list item only. When I override the getHeaderId() method and return 1, it puts the header at the very top of the list instead of at the top of the second item. The scrolling is also really jumpy. Has anyone used this library with some success that might know what's going on?

I'm using MergeAdapter, so could that cause an issue with getting the position of the ListView I set it to?

Here's my adapter code:

```
private class ProfileMergeAdapter extends MergeAdapter implements StickyListHeadersAdapter{

    @Override
    public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater nameInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = (RelativeLayout) nameInflater.inflate(R.layout.name_line, null);
        convertView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        profilePhotoBottom = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic_bottom);
        TextView userName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        userName.setText(Utility.userName);
        profilePhotoBottom.setImageBitmap(photoBMPbot);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getHeaderId(int position) {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

> @Override
>   public long getHeaderId(int position) {
>      return 1;
>   }

If you return 1 here, then every item (at every position) will have a headerId of 1. Therefore you only get one header at the very top. This behaviour is correct.

You should only return the same id for items that should be grouped under the same header.
For example, if you would return position/3; there will be a header over every third item.

Hope this clears things up :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll give it a go tonight.

Comment: So if I want a header over the second item only, I could do an if statement and return 1 if the position is 1 and 0 if the position is anything else?

Comment: I don't know how exactly StickyListHeaders works. My guess would be that this would result in 3 headers (one at the top, one over the second item, and one before the third item). But you should simply try it out ..

Comment: That's exactly what happened. I guess I'll just have to fiddle around some more and see if there are any more methods I can override. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to follow their sample as they did exactly what you want it to do in their sample:

```
@Override
public long getHeaderId(int position) {
  if (position == 0) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

This would skip the first position and return a heading in position 1.